# Linear Regression analysis on selected features - JAVA, WEKA

Tags: java, weka, linear-regression

I want to perform linear regression analysis on selected features, which were obtained by using Feature selection process in java. I know how to perform it in weka but want to do it in java. Can anyone give me an approach on how and where to start also, if possible any sample code on this would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: I see you have posted a new question, is this still one you are interested in?

Comment: @Walter I've found a website for all sample codes. [link] (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.10/weka/attributeSelection/AttributeSelection.java?av=f) . I don't need any help here now, but if you can help for my other question regarding 'Cannot handle multi-valued nominal class' that would be GREAT.